# Why am i getting errors when changing a file from .c to .h?

Tags: c, struct, header

I'm trying to make a header file for use in a program that plots vectors to a coordinate system and the problematic part of the code looks like this:

```
struct vector {
    float x, y;
};
struct vector vectoradd(struct vector V, struct vector W) {
    return (struct vector) {V.x + W.x, V.y + W.y};
}
```

This works flawlessly if I run it as a .c file but if I change the file extension to .h and add `#pragma once`, visual studio underlines this part of the code:

```
return (struct vector) {V.x + W.x, V.y + W.y};
//                     ^
```

This seems pretty bizarre to me but note that this is one of the first header files I have ever made.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: In visual studio it says "expected an expression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its moving your code from .c to .h is what causing the problem, because .h files are compiled along with the .c files that include them. Any chance the original file has been indeed a .c file, yet the new file that includes the .h is a **.cpp**?

If that's the case, can't you just use a temp variable instead of non-standard syntax? Also, i'd add `inline` as well, if i'd really want it in the .h and replicated everywhere that badly:

```
inline struct vector vectoradd(struct vector V, struct vector W) 
{
    struct vector tmp = {V.x + W.x, V.y + W.y};
    return tmp;
};
```

Comment: It seems that visual c++ thinks I'm making a header file for a cpp file and gives me an error. Since bools don't exist in c I made a bool and it didn't give me an error so I think this really is the case. If I include that header in a c file it works flawlessly so that error wasn't really an error